# Repeatedly loading AJAX content on responsive page

Tags: jquery, ajax, responsive-design

I've got the following website http://rangeessentials.petersenuploads.co.uk/

The page uses a slightly modified responsive framework to load auxilliary content via AJAX when the screen width is above a certain size (480px). However, if you resize the screen to a narrow width and refresh and then make it wider, I get duplicate content loaded. I'm checking if content is loaded (look in init.js), but it seems to be ignored. I can't figure out what's going on. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `$.ajax` is asynch. Depending on how fast the server-side function is `loadLeftAux()` for example will fire mutiple times before the `success` function has added the content and the class. The if statement won't work until the first ajax call has returned it's response and added the content. When the content is appended you've already started more ajax calls that will finish and add more content.

What you have to do is that you have to determine if yo have an ajax-call running before you're sending a new request.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. It's only a time bit of content to load. How do I implement $.active, within my code?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the best solution for you.

One example could be like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RsuwN/1/) if there is an active request running, abort it before sending a new one. IE only the last request that is sent will be able to finish. 

Otherwise add the class when sending the request like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eJCnZ/2/), this is not so good if the request fails you want get any content.

Comment: Thanks albin. I went with the second option as this is only auxiliary content and not critical to the page.